# How to iterate over a list of objects and generate an excel file out of those objects?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to produce an excel file containing records of the objects in a list. I get a file with only the last record. It seems that the records over write each other. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
class dog:
    def __init__(self, id,type, name, age):
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
dogs = []
for i in range (10):
    newDog = dog(i, 'any', 'any2', i+1)
    dogs.append(newDog)

fname = "StatisticsDogs.xlsx"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fname, engine='xlsxwriter')
for d in dogs:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'dog ID':[d.id], 'dog NAme':[d.name]})
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using xlsxwriter:

```py
import xlsxwriter

class dog:
    def __init__(self, id,type, name, age):
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

dogs = []
for i in range (10):
    newDog = dog(i, 'any', 'any2', i+1)
    dogs.append(newDog)


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('StatisticsDogs.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for row_num, dog in enumerate(dogs):
    worksheet.write(row_num, 0, dog.id)
    worksheet.write(row_num, 1, dog.name)
    worksheet.write(row_num, 2, dog.age)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the answer is:

```
import pandas as pd 
class dog:
    def __init__(self, id,type, name, age):
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
dogs = []
for i in range (10):
    newDog = dog(i, 'any', 'any2', i+1)
    dogs.append(newDog)
lisIDs = []
lisNames = []
for d in dogs:
    lisIDs.append(d.id)
    lisNames.append(d.name)
fname = "StatisticsDogs.xlsx"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fname, engine='xlsxwriter')
for d in dogs:
    #df = pd.DataFrame({'dog ID':[d.id], 'dog NAme':[d.name]})
    df = pd.DataFrame({'dog ID':lisIDs, 'dog NAme':lisNames})
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there you could also use the python xlwt library: https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/ to create an excel file to store the dog information

Here is an example of how you could potentially do such a thing:

```
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook

class dog_type:
    def __init__(self, id, type, name, age):
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        filename = "put filename here.xls"
        sheetname = 'sheet name'
        wb = Workbook()
        sheet = wb.add_sheet(sheetname)
        sheet.write(1, 0, id)
        sheet.write(2, 0, type)
        sheet.write(3, 0, name)
        sheet.write(4, 0, age)
        wb.save(filename)

dog_type('dog id', 'dog type', 'dog name', 'dog age')
```

You are essentially using a Workbook to add the proper information into your excel spreadsheet. The `Workbook` function is xlwt's way of storing information similar to how pandas `pd.DataFrame` function serves the purpose of storing your dog identification. here is some documentation to understand more what it does in a more detailed fasion: https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to iterate over the list of objects. Also this code gives this error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwt' ". Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see well you can fix the ModuleNotFound error with pip install xlwt if you already have pip installed. I will modify my answer to accommodate an extra list of dog objects. And your welcome.